# File log on centos and jboss?

Tags: linux, jboss, log4j, centos

This is my configuration file of log4j, on Windows works fine but on centos only create the in /tmp/ControllerDebug.log file and nothing is written in it.

I have checked that it isn´t a problem of permissions.
My server is jboss.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/' >

<appender name="FileDebugAp" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
 <param name="file" value="${log.dir}/Controller_Debug.log" />
 <param name="MaxFileSize" value="8000KB"/>
 <!-- Keep one backup file -->
 <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="1"/>
 <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
  <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %5p %c{1} - %m%n" />
 </layout>
 <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
  <param name="levelMin" value="DEBUG" />
  <param name="levelMax" value="FATAL" />
 </filter>
</appender>

<appender name="ConsoleErrorAp" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
  <param name="Target" value="System.err"/>
  <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
   <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p %c{1} - %m%n"/>
  </layout>
  <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
   <param name="levelMin" value="ERROR" />
   <param name="levelMax" value="FATAL" />
 </filter>
</appender>

<logger name="com.optimi.xgeomanager" additivity="false">
 <level value="ALL"/>

<appender-ref ref="FileDebugAp"/>
</logger>
<logger name="com.optimi.tps" additivity="false">
 <level value="ALL"/>

<appender-ref ref="FileDebugAp"/>
</logger>
<root>
 <priority value="DEBUG" />
 <appender-ref ref="ConsoleInfoAp"/>
</root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I resolved this adding jboss-deployment-structure.xml file with this information:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
 <deployment>
    <!-- Exclusions allow you to prevent the server from automatically adding 
        some dependencies -->
    <exclusions>
        <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
        <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
    </exclusions>
 </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```